# Is it normal for the Canon 6D to exhibit more color noise compared to a 50D?

Tags: canon, sensor, color, noise, canon-6d

My first day with 6D, upgraded from a 50D. Wouldn't be pixel-peeping but something unusual caught my eye when I opened photos in Lightroom this morning. The color noise pattern is completely different when compared to the 50D and it is more difficult to get rid of it as well. See all those red, green and blue pixels? None of that appears on the photo from a 50D. It is worth mentioning that I boosted the exposure a bit in both images to make it more prominent. See here: 
https://flic.kr/p/oT89pe

The question is whether this is normal for 6D?

Comment: Both were shot in RAW? Did the lighting change at all between shots? What software did you use for post?

Comment: Both were shot in RAW one after the other. Lighting conditions did not change. The link shows images exported from Lightroom with no changes except exposure boost, same in both.

Comment: You can compare the two directly on this site: http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canon-eos-6d/23 - It doesn't look normal to me. I have a 6D and have never seen what you are experiencing either.

Comment: The thing is that I did not spot that kind of noise in short exposures (fractions of a second) at high ISO. It only appears at very long exposures (the photos shown were both about 250 seconds).

Comment: This is not uncommon for very long exposures, such as in the minutes like yours. You heat up the sensor and that creates the noise you see. Lightroom's color noise reduction can remove it well enough. I usually apply some luminance noise reduction afterwards and that seems to also help.

Comment: The 6D image looks underexposed.

Comment: Was the same ISO, Aperture, and shutter speed used for both images? Were the lighting conditions the same?

Comment: It looks weird, but you say on Flickr that long exp noise reduction was off. If it goes away with NR on, I would not worry about it.

Comment: Without the relevant exif information on both images its hard to say what is going on, but I would guess that the 6D is missing the dark frame subtraction, did you disable something like that?

Comment: Fist I cannot directly see your images, as Yahoo is requiring a login to do so.  IT is best to put images where anyone can see them for posting to sites like this.   Secondly I note you say you *boosted exposure a bit*, presumably in software.  That will have a similar effect to raising ISO, and so make any noise way more visible than it would otherwise be.  I would say that pixel peeping, particularly from RAW, is just something that will drive you nuts, because if you go looking for a problem that won't be visible in a print, you will find it.